# In Pandas, how do I find column and row names using their numeric location?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing an embedded for loop looking for abnormalities in my dataset. The loop works fine, but I'm trying to print out the name of the row and column for each abnormality. So the code looks something like this:

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if (np.abs((df.iloc[i][j+1] / df.iloc[i][j])-1) > 0.5):
            print(i, j)
```

Except instead of printing "i, j", I want to print out the name of the index for each row as well as the column header. How would I do this?

I did try:

```
df.iloc[0].index
```

And quite a few variations of that, but the above code returns all the column headers, while df.iloc[:,0] returns all the row names. Is there any way to specifically get, for instance, the name of the 4th row and the 4th column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
print(df.index[i], df.columns[j])
```

Comment: That's less complicated than my solution. Should've thought of that. Thanks!